# jQuery selector for multiple elements

Tags: jquery

I know this isn't a code issue related question, but it's something I'd love to know and it may help others:

What's the difference between using this:

```
$(function() {
    var $fullArea = $('#full-sized-area');
    var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
});
```

Over say this:

```
$(function() {
    var $fullArea = $('#full-sized-area');
    var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content, #full-sized-area');
});
```

Comment: Generally the 2 codes are totally different. The first selects just 1 element having id `#full-sized-content` ***under*** the element `$fullArea`, so if that element is not contained in `$fullArea`, you receive an empty jquery object. While the second always returns 2 objects of `#full-sized-content` and `#full-sized-area`. Of course those ids should exist in the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference,

**[Demo : Multiple selector](http://jsfiddle.net/93k2t/)**

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content, #full-sized-area');
```

Selects both the elements - **[Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**: `$('#elem1,#elem2,...')`

---

**[Demo: Parent-child](http://jsfiddle.net/93k2t/1/)**

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
```

In this case : `#full-sized-content` has to the child of `#full-sized-area`

So its is equivalent to

```
$('#full-sized-area #full-sized-content');
          Parent          Child
```

Answer (score 2):

Both are quite difference.

Basically you are using [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in the following line. So its simple

```
$('#full-sized-content, #full-sized-area')
```

Where as in line you are using context based selector, Here you are selecting element with ID `full-sized-content` in childs of `$fullArea`

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
```

is equivalent to

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-area').find('#full-sized-content');
```

Note As IDs must be unique in HTML you can simply use

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content');
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are diffent here..

```
$(function() {
    var $fullArea = $('#full-sized-area');
    var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
});
```

This one select  element which has id "full-sized-content" under the #full-sized-area element

```
$(function() {
    var $fullArea = $('#full-sized-area');
    var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content, #full-sized-area');
});
```

This one select both element with the ID full-sized-content and full-sized-area

Answer (score 1):

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
```

The above actually a context based selector. So, what is does in simple manner is:-

```
$fullArea                           // get the fullArea element
    .find('#full-sized-content')    // find all the descendants with this id inside it
```

While the code below means:

```
// Get both the elements with id full-sized-content & full-sized-area
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content, #full-sized-area');
```

It's like a combined selector. So, if you do the below thing for 1st code:-

```
$fullContent.css('color', 'red');
```

It will only make the color red for the element `#full-sized-content` inside `$fullArea`
Whereas if you use the same code for the 2nd part, it will color both the `full-sized-content` & `full-sized-area` elements.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw4Qa/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
```

it says find me  `#full-sized-content` in `$fullArea`, because of the `,`. `,` makes a context for this.

---

This code:

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content, #full-sized-area');
```

is usually called a **muliple selector selection** which is a string with `,` separated elems while below

```
var $fullContent = $('#full-sized-content', $fullArea);
```

is usually finds an element in a given context which is `,` separated elems.

Comment: @AmitKumar details added you can take a look.